# Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as expression. This expression is not callable. Typescript - Vue.js

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I'm facing an error that won't let me load the page I'm working on.
In my components directory I have the MyButton.vue file.

```
<template>
  <button>My Button</button>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import {Component, Vue} from "vue-property-decorator";


  @Component
  export default class MyButton extends Vue{

  }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

And on my Home.vue it should load the page and display the button itself but somehow I get an error.

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <MyButton></MyButton>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
  import MyButton from "@/components/MyButton.vue";

  @Component({
    components:{
      MyButton
    },
  })
  export default class Home extends Vue {}
</script>
```